# What's the origin of Crespi plates?

Tags: ancient-history, cultural-history, archaeology

I've found this article about [The Mysterious Crespi Collection & The Metal Library](http://redicecreations.com/article.php?id=22094)

And there is a picture of The enigmatic Crespi plate:

[image]

And it's said:

> The age and origin of these items is still unknown today.
>
> These objects show the pictures of an unknown culture.
>
> The most well known pieces are tablets made of silver, gold foil or other alloys with unknown letters and mysterious symbols.

This is what was posted few years ago.

Is it really we don't know to which culture this seal belong to? How come?

---

See also:

- [The Crespi Ancient Artifact Collection of Cuenca Ecuador](http://chapmanresearch.org/PDF/Crespi%20Ancient%20Artifact%20Collection%20of%20Cuenca%20%20Ecuador.pdf)

  > A Crespi Gold Plate with Written and Zodiacal Characters
- [Father Crespi and the Ancient Metallic library (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N44e6FjN5gs)

  > J. Golden Barton gives his account of visiting father crespi in Ecuador, and of all the fascinating ancient artifacts he was able to see and photograph. This was given at the Ancient Historical Research Foundation symposium held a BYU on 5-25-05
  >
  > Dr. Guistavo Reinoso Hermidia, of Cuenca, and Dr. Olaf Holm, Director of the Museo del Banco Central of Guayaguil, both archaelogist. Some 8000 pieces of ceramics, including hundreds of truly superb examples, were transferred to the Museo for cataloguing.
- [Archaeological Discoveries of Ancient America (book)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1477728090)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on skeptics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Look like forgeries to me. In any case, it belongs on skeptics SE, not history.

Comment: @TylerDurden Are you saying this plate [isn't real](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H0sxtOsXMqA)?

Comment: It's probably real, just not old.

Comment: I cannot find any credible evidence that they are historical artifacts.

Comment: Interesting, but I have to agree with @TylerDurden: as long as the owner of those plates doesn't bother to allow proper historians to study them, it's a hoax "until proven otherwise".

Comment: I've found another article regarding this plate: [The Crespi Ancient Artifact Collection of Cuenca Ecuador](http://chapmanresearch.org/PDF/Crespi%20Ancient%20Artifact%20Collection%20of%20Cuenca%20%20Ecuador.pdf). It's saying: 'A Crespi Gold Plate with Written and Zodiacal Characters'. However I'm not sure if that specific one is a fake.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything definitive about this. So yes, it appears to be true that **there is no consensus on the plates**.

One likelihood is of course that they are a hoax (sadly, its [been known to happen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kensington_Runestone)).

If they end up being authentic, given where they were found, my *conjecture* would be that they are the only known exemplars of a proto-Incan writing system that didn't survive to the colonial period. I base this on them being found in a historical Incan area, and on the fact that they are similar in structure, but totally different in glyph style, to Mayan codex's (see below).

[image]

Notice how the glyphs are arranged in a grid pattern, but the glyphs themselves have a very rounded look compared to the Ecuadorian plates. Very much like what we'd see if the system was borrowed but adapted to a different language.

I've noticed others on the internet making this same speculation, but none that have any noticeable expertise.

It appears that the current holders of the plates will not make them available to the public. So I'd say until they are studied extensively by experts (eg: some kind of dating would be wonderful), they are best viewed as an intriguing one-off find that could quite possibly be a hoax.

Comment: No Mayans in Ecuador TED.

Comment: @TylerDurden - There are also no Sumerians in the Indus Valley. However, there were trade links, and it is thought their writing system may have come that way rather than being completely locally invented. This is the kind of mechanism I am thinking of.

Comment: @TylerDurden - ...but again, that's just speculation. Occam's Razor would tell us we need to rule out a hoax before assuming anything that extravagant. You're absolutely right there.

Answer (score 0):

According to Ancient American ([No. 68](http://www.ancientamerican.com/aa/index.php/back-issues)), this "Zodiac Plate" is a grid of fifty-six symbols which are embossed on a 51x13 inch oblong sheet of unoxidized copper alloy.

[Fell Barry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barry_Fell) considered this [a Paphian script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cypriot_syllabary#Paleography) which accompanying the corresponding Zodiac sings.

References:

- Fell, Barry, 1985, Perietal Inscriptions of the Anubis Caves, Epigraphic Society Occasional Papers, 14 #342

Professor Fox, author of Gods of the Cataclysm (1976) had been drawn to Cuenca, because of the similarities between the "Zodiac Plate" and [Indus Valley script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indus_script). Please check [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUWSRTTPQ00) of Prof. Dileep Kumar Kanjilal who talks about decipheration of the Cuenca Script of Ecuador.

Comment: As near as I can tell, these are all claiming either old-world or even worse Atlantian origins for the script, which is such an extraordinary and seemingly-unlikely claim that it would need some seriously extraordinary evidence to back it up.